# Code Igniter select active record in model not working

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, select

I want to select and then `var_dump` the database rows, but I cant since `var_dump` is returning the `bool(false)`.

My model: (players.php).

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Players extends CI_Model
{
    private $table_name = 'players';

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get($id = FALSE)
    {
        $this->db->select();
        $this->db->where('ban <', time());
        if ( $id )
            $this->db->where('id =', $id);

        $query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);
        return $query->num_rows() == 0;
    }
}

/* End of file test.php */
/* Location: ./application/models/test.php */
```

My player.php controller:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Player extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('tank_auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('players');
        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view('default');
        var_dump($this->players->get());
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
}

/* End of file player.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/player.php */
```

Have you any solutions for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->where('id =', $id);
```

is incorrect

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);
```

is correct. You don't need the = operand with a normal `WHERE =`; use operands for `<`, `>`, `!=`

Also,

```
return $query->num_rows() == 0;
```

will return `bool false` if you have more than 0 rows (i.e. if you have any users with `ban < time()`. Try returning just `$query` and `var_dump`'ing that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I just return the `$query` the result looks like this: `object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#21 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> resource(9) of type (mysql link persistent) ["result_id"]=> resource(19) of type (mysql result) ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["row_data"]=> NULL }`

Comment: Never mind, just forgot to add `$query->result()`. Thank you :)